# Android Watch fullscreen FAB like the DismissOverlay

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, watch

There is the DismissOverlayView, which you can implement to give the user an alternative way to exit the application on an android watch. This View implements something, that looks like a fullscreen FAB. Now I would like to know, how I could implement the same View with another button icon/color/behaviour. Since you can't change the DismissOverlayView which code looks btw. like this :

```
<android.support.wearable.view.DismissOverlayView
    android:id="@+id/dismiss_overlay"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
```

[image]

I guess you have to implement some custom FAB, but I can't use the FAB in my watch XML either because there is an dependency missing or because it's simply not supported by the watch os. I tried following code for testing :

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:clickable="true"/>
```

Edit: For better understanding, I want the button look like this :

[image]

Edit: I just found this solution, I was not aware of that one :

https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/ui/confirm.html

But I would still be curious, if you could implement a more customisable version of this buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found a solution for that problem, actually you can simply create a new layout.xml and overwrite the default code, which is the following one :

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dismiss_overlay_explain"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:padding="12dp"
        style="@style/DismissOverlayText"
        />
    <android.support.wearable.view.ActionPage
        android:id="@+id/dismiss_overlay_button"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/dismiss_overlay_bg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_full_cancel"
        android:color="@color/dismiss_close"
        app:buttonRippleColor="@color/dismiss_close_pressed"
        android:text="@string/dismiss_overlay_button_label"
        />
</merge>
```

Now you can use your newly created xml customise it and use this one instead of the original dimissOverlayView. But you should be careful with doing so, because this is not really intended from the design guidelines to do.